# CSS: Doubts with padding behaviour

Tags: html, css, padding, spacing

I am working with 2 DIVs, in a way that one lies above the other. And more things than expected happens when I increase the padding-top value of the first DIV.

The HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="EX7.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="first">
          <p>Um parágrafo com 3 span: <span>SPAN A </span><span>SPAN B </span><span>SPAN C</span>
  </div>

  <div id="second">
             <p>* A fonte do parágrafo tem 20pt, e a dos span tem 8pt.</p>
  </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS code:

```
body{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

#first{
width:100%;
height:70px;
background-color:green;
border-bottom:4px solid black;
margin-top:-30px;
padding-top:0px;
}

#second{
margin-top:-27px;
padding-top:-5px;
width:100%;
height:70px;
background-color:green;
}

#first p, #second p{
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size:20pt;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

With this code, my page is the following:

[image]

Notice the border separating the 2 DIVs. Also notice the `padding-top:0px` property of the `#first` DIV. Now cames my question: If I change this property to `padding-top:1px`, a strange behavior appears:

[image]

Notice that the content of the `#first` DIV really keeps 1px away of it's top, as expected. **But the space between the bottom of the content of the `#first` DIV and the top of the `#second` one disappears, and I didn't undertand why**.

I would appreciate your help so much. Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jpvsjmz5/ is this what ur lookin for ?

Comment: Go through 'CSS Box Model' and understand how margin,padding,border works http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp. All the best

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
body{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

#first{
width:100%;
height:70px;
background-color:green;
border-bottom:4px solid black;
padding-top:0px;
}

#second{
width:100%;
height:70px;
background-color:green;
}

#first p, #second p{
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size:20pt;
font-weight:bold;
}

p{
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 2.6em;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="first">
    <p>Um parágrafo com 3 span: <span>SPAN A </span><span>SPAN B </span><span>SPAN C</span></p>
</div>

<div id="second">
     <p>* A fonte do parágrafo tem 20pt, e a dos span tem 8pt.</p>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/g9xcu1og/)**